# How to update the speicific field in array of objects in mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

Hi there i wanted to update status field in messages.
I'm trying to use

```
db.messagev2.updateMany(
  {
    user1: 8, user2:150,
   "messages.receiver":150,
   "messages.status" : "sent",
    },
{'$set': {'messages.$.status': "read"}},{multi:true})
```

but only the first status in message is updating .. Need help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace:

```
  'messages.$.status'
```

with:

```
  'messages.$[elem].status'
```

And add $arrayFilters :

```
    { arrayFilters: [ { "elem.receiver": 150 ,"elem.status": "sent"} ] }
```

Comment: Thank you bro for replying i exact did this 

MessageV2.updateMany(
      { user1: user1, user2: user2 },
      { $set: { "messages.$[elem].status": "read" } },
      {
        arrayFilters: [
          { $and: [{ "elem.status": "sent" }, { "elem.sender": data.sender }] }
        ]
      }


but in mongodb compass this is working but in my node it is not

Comment: Hi there can you help sir

Comment: Node? , Version? , Error message?

Comment: Node version  v16.5.0
mongo version v5.0.0
Error message is nothing the callback result is undefined
as data in the db is not updating

Comment: You can add the not working code to the ticket otherways I dont see how we can help ...

Comment: Oh!... okay i'll add ticket in the mongodb